# Class won't compile in Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dynamic

I'm learning about Servlets/jsps and have some test classes written.  Everything seems to work as expected, the only problem I'm running into is being able to compile a simple Java class.  This is the class:

```
package ilya.model;

public class DatabaseConnection {

public String getConnection()
{
    String result;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        System.out.println("found the driver");
        result = "Connection established!";
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("No driver");
        result = "No Connection";
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

The jsp trying to access it is pretty simple and I don't think it has anything to do with it.  If anyone wants me to post it let me know.

Here's the Exception I receive when class is initialised for the first time:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 15 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. ilya.model.DatabaseConnection resolves to a package
```

This compile fine in a regular Java project.  Any ideas?

**Update**
Here is the JSP file.  It's actually working now.  I tried the same project on a different machine and everything worked.  Must be something wrong with Eclipse.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="ilya.model.BeerSuggestor, ilya.model.DatabaseConnection" %>
<%! 
int count=0; 
String connect;

public void jspInit() {
        ServletConfig sconfig = getServletConfig();
        String lname = sconfig.getInitParameter("lastName");
        ServletContext context = sconfig.getServletContext();
        context.setAttribute("lastName", lname);
    }
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">      
<html>
<head>
<%-- DatabaseConnection intialized here --%>
<% 
DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
connect = db.getConnection(); 
%>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>The count is: <%= this.count++ %></p>
<p>The count is: <%= 500 %></p>
<p>The count is: <%= config.getInitParameter("lastName") %></p>

<%-- Value of connect printed here --%>
<p>The connection result is: <%=" " + connect %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is in your JSP, please post it. The server cannot compile the JSP, it's not about your Java class ('Unable to compile class for JSP').

Comment: Agreed; the JSP has something to do with it, perhaps how you're trying to import. Not that we should be importing classes into a JSP.

Comment: I also tried adding a main method, and compiling/running the class on its own.  It wouldn't compile either.

Comment: I'll post the JSP later, I don't have it in front of me. Basically there's a an import statement: <%@ page import="ilya.model.DatabaseConnection" %>... and later a jspInit() method that instantiates DatabaseConnection (line 15).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have plain Java in JSP files as you show here..

Create a separate class in the appropriate source folder inside Eclipse for this.

Comment: Your build system is broken.  Try exporting to a WAR and investigate the WEB-INF/classes hierarchy.

Comment: I think your right, the build system isn't working.  I tried the same project on another computer and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with previous comments. It looks like, you are trying to establish a database connection directly from your JSP.

Please check the line in JSP, specially where you are setting the driver in jsp.

You can try this from your jsp as well.

```
<%
 Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
 Connection myConn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbcostgresql://localhost/db_name?user=db_user&password=db_pwd");
%>
```

Comment: There's only an import directive and instantiation of a DatabaseConnection object in a jspInit() method in the JSP.

Comment: jspInit() method is the generated method during translation phase of JSP. Whatever you write in the jsp will be translated in a java class. Have you tried writing a scriptlet to connect to your database?

Comment: Maybe it was just init().  I'm going from memory.  I know it worked fine until I added the import statement and object instantiation. I'll post the actual JSP in about 3 hours when I get home.